# SQL Server: Double data size of a table when altering column type

Tags: sql-server-2008, alter-column

I altered the type of a column in to an actual smaller type:

```
-- change type from nvarchar(100) to varchar(50)
Alter Table [MyTable] Alter column [MyColumn] varchar(50)
```

The table contains 4 Mio. records. Before it used around 1.1 GB of space, after the altering of the column, it uses 2.2 GB space. Is there any explanation for that?

I find the space it uses either by SMO or by looking at the table properties in the sql server management studio: "MyTable -> Properties -> Storage -> Data space". Now I doubt that this is the actual space used by the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `ALTER INDEX ALL On MyTable REBUILD` and then check space again with the "true" flag

Basically, the change in type has fragmented storage somehow: for example it is now NULLable and it wasn't before which affects the on-disk structures. I chose this example because you have not specified NULL/NOT NULL in your ALTER TABLE

Comment: That's it. After rebuilding the indexes it went back to 1.1 GB. It's still funny that the space used gets higher when the table is fragmented. I believed that it is a measure of amount of data in the table, but it is more saying how much space it occupies on the disk.

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger: correct, it's allocated space. The change of datatype may not affetc how may rows per 8k page (page density), so you have the same structure on disk. All you'd have is slightly less data in each page.

Answer (score 0):

With sp_spaceused you can get more info about the space used by your table.

```
EXEC sp_spaceused @objname = N'dbo.MyTable' ,@updateusage = N'TRUE';
```

Comment: The same: it shows data size of 2307256 KB, index size of 788488 KB.